# Extract patent data from google in Microsoft word

Tags: vba, webbrowser-control, ms-word

I want to extract patent claims from googlepatents to microsoft word table.
Is it possible to extract data with formatting and having embedded images?
I am novice in the field.
I tried using VBA bu could not get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is that this seems like a very difficult way of going about this. In my experience, Google Patents is a very rough data set with slightly different encoding used from one batch of patents to the other.

An alternative may be to use a service like [PatentData.io](http://patentdata.io/). It provides a simple RESTful api which allows you to easily access claims by patent number and claim number. They're still in Beta, but it's pretty slick.

Comment: No, it's actually not free.  It's kind of a more robust product used for production applications.  They have been rolled into IP Street.  IP Street offers a free trial however.  Check it out: http://www.ipstreet.com/

Comment: Reed, you appear to be affiliated with IP Street ("Head of Product", per LinkedIn). You should disclose that when you post answers positing your commercial product or service as a solution, so that readers understand they're getting as much of an advertisement as they are an answer. I note that most of your answers here suggest using your company's product.

Comment: That is a good point, @codingatty.  Never really tried to hide that I work for IP Street. It's well published on [my StackOverflow developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/3372041).  It wouldn't hurt for me to also include this information inline when I suggest that IP Street can solve the Questioner's problem.  Good advice. Thanks.